# Web Google pay not showing on mobile using android (cordova)

Tags: android, vue.js, cordova, vue-component

I am using this package https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/tree/main/src/button-element
that Google provided for web component.

Currently using Quasar framework, I had no problem when viewing on browser but when I try in Android the Google Pay button is not showing. I have also PayPal button components and it shows in cordova mode.